# Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSObject

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion

I'm getting the following error when running a Mac app in OS X 10.7.3 (Lion):

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSObject
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/Desktop/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/SBJson.framework/Versions/A/SBJson
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
```

The app runs fine on OS X 10.8.1 (Mountain Lion) and was built with XCode 4.4 in Mountain Lion. SBJson is a private framework.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set your deployment target to 10.7.

Answer (score 3):

The `OS X Deployment Target` value in the Build Settings of your linked libraries must less than or equal to the `OS X Deployment Target` of your main app's Xcode target.

(yes, it's confusing as "target" has dual meaning here: "Deployment Target" vs. "Xcode Target")